# Should a patent claim (all) possible applications?

Tags: patent-applications, germany

Do I have to claim future applications of an intervention? Do I need an application at all?

In this [article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patentrecht_(Deutschland)#Einf%C3%BChrung) it is written:

> Zwar wird in Patentanmeldungen üblicherweise nur eine Erfindung
> beschrieben, jedoch werden in den Patentansprüchen (englisch: claims),
> speziell wenn eine grundsätzliche Idee beansprucht werden soll, oft
> alle möglichen Implementierungen und (auch erst in Zukunft entdeckte)
> Verwendungen der Idee beansprucht.
>
> Although patent applications usually describe only one invention, claims, especially when a basic idea is to be claimed, often claim all
> possible implementations and (even future discovered) uses of the
> idea.

I thought only for medical applications like the use of drugs it is possible to claim an existing patent for a different application.
But for a, let's assume some mechanical component or whatsoever, I have to foresee all possible applications? Otherwise it is free to use (for a specific non-claimed application) for everyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a lawyer, but here is my take. A patent only protects what is in the claims. If you don't claim it, you don't own it. Thus, it is usually a good idea to attempt to claim useful permutations of the invention. This doesn't mean you will get every claim awarded, but you certainly won't get what you don't attempt to claim. Now the rest of the application needs to support the claims which is why some, if not most, patent attorneys draft the claims first when writing an application.

> But for a, let's assume some mechanical component or whatsoever, I
> have to foresee all possible applications? Otherwise it is free to use
> (for a specific non-claimed application) for everyone?

If someone finds a use for your invention that isn't protected by a use/method claim *and you do not have a device claim*, then that application may be free for them to use. With a device claim all uses of the device would be protected.
They might even be able to get a patent on that new use and keep you from using your own invention in the new way. Having a claim publish in an application, even if it doesn't get granted might help protect against this. This is one reason I always council inventors to work with a patent attorney or agent, especially with inventions that have potentially a wide range of uses. Patenting often is best pursued with strategic thinking which might mean several patents that complement each other.

Comment: Specifically related to a mechanical device or other physical thing - a use claim and an apparatus claim are two separate things. One patent might include one, the other, or both. If you have an apparatus claim, any use of it necessarily includes one of your devices. Where did they get it - from you or your licensee or there is an infringement of your device claim.

Comment: @Eric: Thank you for your answers! I realized that a patent has to be an (applicable) solution for a problem, so, yes, it should contain at least one possible application. Nevertheless, as you elaborated, I'm quite surprised that, e.g., I invent something and couldn't foresee everything. Sure, on the other hand, there is a certain achievement when others see possible applications I didn't, but getting prevented from using my own invention is kind of weird.
However, thanks for clearifying!

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I'm a bit confused now. Does that mean that when having an apparatus claim (is that US law?) would involve all applications like I assumed in the first place?

Comment: @Ben Lets say you invent the laser. You own that and no one can use lasers in the way claimed by your patent without paying you. If someone patents the use of a laser to detect vehicle speed, you can't use your laser to detect vehicle speed without licencing from that person. He still might need to license from you depending on your patent's claims. You can still use your laser for all the purposes claimed in your patent. The new patent doesn't change that.

Comment: @EricS - I think this comment misses the distinction between a claim to a thing and a method claim to the use of a thing.

Comment: @EricS - in your answer you say that someone who comes up with a new use for a patented mechanical component can practice that use. That is incorrect. The patent on the mechanical component gives the owner the right to prohibit any use (or sale or importation or making etc.). On the other hand if the original patent was of one specific use, not the thing itself, then a new use could be patented.  I think you should re-wok the answer.

Comment: @EricS And - it is fundamental that patent rights do not give the owner any positive right to practice their patent, only to exclude others.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I think I was clear that if someone patents a new use of a device it only protects the new use and doesn't mean the original inventor of the device loses any protection of their patent.

Comment: No patent causes any other patent to ever loose anything.

Comment: @EricS "If someone finds a use for your invention that isn't protected by a claim, then yes it is free for them to use it." That is flat wrong in two regards. One, I think you are still in the context above "some mechanical component " and If one gets a claim to a mechanical component, itself, one has the right to try to stop anyone making, selling, importing or using. That is all uses. Second it implies that having a patent means one is allowed to practice the patent, that is a common misconception. I really think you should re-work the answer.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I attempted to improve the answer based on your latest comments. Thanks, as always, on the feedback.

Comment: I made a small edit and upvoted,

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The comments have gotten confusing. First, something fundamental that often gets misunderstood. Your patent doesn't entitle you to do *anything* at all. Patent owners can only (attempt to) stop others from practicing the patent. Patents are a right to exclude, not to perform. There may be patents of others that would be infringed by practicing your patent or even laws that would be broken in the process.

Second, there is a difference between a claim to a *thing*, a device for example, and a particular *method of use* of a thing. If you claim the device as a thing then any future system that contains that device will infringe your device claim regardless of the purpose/use of that future device. This is the case in all patent jurisdictions. If you patent a widget then no one can make, offer for sale, sell, import or *use* a widget without your OK.

A granted apparatus claim might be - "I claim a device that has the following structure . . . ".  That claim wording does not claim any specific method of using the device but the physical device itself. Anyone with a novel use of the device in the future might get a patent on that novel use. But, in using it, they need to physically have a device. That's how you get them.

A different claim type is a method claim. "I claim the method of (a) putting a widget under a board (b) balancing on the board . . . " this does not protect making, selling, importing the widget or protect uses of a widget in general - only the specific use.

If you patent the thing and someone later patents a specific novel use for your thing they can't practice their patent without your OK if your patent is still in force becasue it involves a use of your thing. Neither can you practice their patent.

Comment: I would only clarify your last paragraph a little bit: what you stated is right, but the method can be invented later on, either during the 20-year period or even later, so the patent for the apparatus will be expired at that point in time. And regarding the question, this clearly shows that, whenever possible, you should protect all the possible applications, when applications is understood as procedures.

Comment: thanks - i added "if your patent is still in force".

Comment: would a novel use of a "prior art" physical thing/device be a valid patent then? (even more interesting if the prior art patent is even expired)
Example: shoes with springs have been already patented by nike.
I patent shoes with hydraulic suspensions for riding a windsurf (assuming that this is a thing and has an advantage). This could be seen as a prior art, or close enough, but the use, stabilizing the riding of the surf instead of absorbing walking/running impacts with the ground (so likely with some modifications compared to the original patent) would be new?

Comment: This should be a new question. The patent state of something proposed as prior art is completely irrelevant.